# Similar Jobs in two different Servers

Tags: sql-server, jobs

Can anyone just help me with a script to find similar SQL jobs in two different instances/servers?

By similar I mean jobs with the same name, which do the same task, with the same frequency and schedule.

Comment: Is either instance defined as a linked server at the other? What does "does the same task" mean? There could be different ways of doing the same task that would hard to match programmatically. And what does "the same frequency and schedule" mean? Do you mean just "the same schedule"?

Answer (score 1):

If you've only got two instances just run something like the following against each and compare...

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
    ,j.job_id AS JobID
    ,j.NAME AS JobName
    ,j.enabled AS JobEnabled
    ,j.description AS JobDescription
    ,j.date_created AS JobCreated
    ,j.date_modified AS JobLastModified
    ,l.NAME AS JobOwner
    ,ss.schedule_id AS ScheduleID
    ,ss.enabled AS ScheduleEnabled
    ,sjs.next_run_date
    ,sjs.next_run_time
FROM msdb..sysjobs j
LEFT JOIN master.sys.syslogins l ON j.owner_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN msdb..sysjobschedules sjs ON sjs.job_id = j.job_id
LEFT JOIN msdb..sysschedules ss ON ss.schedule_id = sjs.schedule_id
```

Maybe it's just me but it sounds like one of those things where you need to just grab the data from each and look at it. It doesn't sound like you have specific enough definitions of the term 'similar' to write a sure-fire script.

Answer (score 1):

If the jobs have similar names or steps, you could query their metadata. You can open SQL Server Management Studio, and add both servers to the same Registered Servers group (on the left hand side), you can right click the group to run a new query against both servers at once. Job properties are held in the `[msdb].[dbo].` schema, and in the `sysjobs`, `sysjobsteps` and `sysjobschedules` tables.

The below script was written by [Dattatrey Sindol](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/77/dattatrey-sindol/) at [MSSQL Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/)

```
SELECT 
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    , [sDBP].[name] AS [JobOwner]
    , [sCAT].[name] AS [JobCategory]
    , [sJOB].[description] AS [JobDescription]
    , CASE [sJOB].[enabled]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
      END AS [IsEnabled]
    , [sJOB].[date_created] AS [JobCreatedOn]
    , [sJOB].[date_modified] AS [JobLastModifiedOn]
    , [sSVR].[name] AS [OriginatingServerName]
    , [sJSTP].[step_id] AS [JobStartStepNo]
    , [sJSTP].[step_name] AS [JobStartStepName]
    , CASE
        WHEN [sSCH].[schedule_uid] IS NULL THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
      END AS [IsScheduled]
    , [sSCH].[schedule_uid] AS [JobScheduleID]
    , [sSCH].[name] AS [JobScheduleName]
    , CASE [sJOB].[delete_level]
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Never'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'On Success'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'On Failure'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'On Completion'
      END AS [JobDeletionCriterion]
FROM
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[servers] AS [sSVR]
        ON [sJOB].[originating_server_id] = [sSVR].[server_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] AS [sCAT]
        ON [sJOB].[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sJSTP]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJSTP].[job_id]
        AND [sJOB].[start_step_id] = [sJSTP].[step_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[database_principals] AS [sDBP]
        ON [sJOB].[owner_sid] = [sDBP].[sid]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] AS [sJOBSCH]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules] AS [sSCH]
        ON [sJOBSCH].[schedule_id] = [sSCH].[schedule_id]
ORDER BY [JobName]
```